# background-attachment: fixed causes jump when scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, viewport, parallax

After reading lots of topics about my issue, I still can't figure out how to solve it.

Here is a GIF of the problem I'm currently facing:

https://s4.gifyu.com/images/20210302_235317.gif

[image]

As we can see, as I start scrolling into the page, the browser's app top bar (the black part) starts to reduce, which is expected. But at the same time, a light blue block starts to appear at the bottom, which is actually page's body with a background color applied. When I stop scrolling (removing my finger from the screen), everything resizes and appears to be OK. But this causes a "jump" to occur, which is bad.

Note that everything behaves as expected on desktop, where the viewport stays constant. This jump also doesn't occur when `background-attachment` is not `fixed`.

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="styles/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style> 
                body {
                        background-color: powderblue;
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: 0;
                        overflow: scroll;
                        width: 100vw;
                        height: 100vh;
                }

                .box {
                        min-height: 100%;
                        background-size: cover;
                        background-position: center;
                        background-attachment: fixed;
                }

                .one {
                        background-image: url("https://www.lesoir.be/sites/default/files/dpistyles_v2/ena_16_9_extra_big/2020/01/22/node_274673/27378739/public/2020/01/22/B9722319434Z.1_20200122153715_000+GOLFBQVE6.2-0.jpg?itok=SglXj3C31579704194");
                        border: 3px solid green;
                }

                .two {
                        background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0064/7400/6618/articles/Sans_titre_2000x.png?v=1559840071");
                        border: 3px solid #8fd19e;
                }

                .three {
                        background-image: url("https://www.visitflanders.com/fr/binaries/45b1b488-84d1-47ed-a063-4484b5922992_tcm21-132651.jpg");
                        border: 3px solid #ba8b00;
                }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box one"></div>
        <div class="box two"></div>
        <div class="box three"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IOS Safari does not support background-attachment fixed see [link] https://caniuse.com/?search=Background-attachment

Comment: I'm not using Safari, the screenshot and the GIF are taken from my Android device with Chrome browser.